# Changing Icons in the Tauri Application

Tags: tauri

I gave the application an icon with `yarn tauricon`. This succeeded.

However, when checked on macOS, it did not apply to the following two situations

- [Icons for notifications using `sendNotification()`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRHEA.png)
- [Icons in the About panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU7g7.png)

How can these be changed?
The optional argument to `sendNotification()` is the `icon` property, but there seems to be no documentation on what and how to specify it.

Comment: At least the notification icon can only display the app icon in a bundled app (`tauri build`) and will otherwise (`tauri dev`) show the icon of the terminal.
I'd imagine that it's the same for the About panel.

And here's a little bit more documentation on the notification api: https://docs.rs/notify-rust/latest/notify_rust/struct.Notification.html#method.icon

Comment: Thanks, I built it and now everything shows up with app icons, I'm new to Tauri and this was my first build!
I haven't quite figured out the mechanism yet, but hopefully in the future the icons will be reflected in `dev` as well.

Thanks for showing the documentation too. I started doing Tauri because I'm familiar with TS, and I wouldn't have known that there would be scope to look not only at Tauri's documentation, but also at the documentation for Rust itself if you hadn't told me.